# Complex csv data mapping based on tables using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have csv data like:

```
id;12;12;13;13
company;Fox century;Fox century;Apple company;Apple company
ticker;fox;fox;appl;appl
industry code;2;2;3;3
indicator;  Share Price; Common Shares Outstanding;Share Price;Common Shares Outstanding
2011-11-04; 2.72;   65046.232; 2.33; 3443
2012-02-06; 2.89;   65065.558; 2.44; 4242     
2012-05-04; 3.04;   64788.687; 2.44; 2222
.........................................
```

Each row contain id,company,ticker;industrycode;indicator;2011-11-04(date);2012-02-06(date);..etc.

I want to insert this data based on my db model:
I have 2 tables *company,Indicator*

company tables has 4 column:Id(primary_key),companyname,ticker,industry code
**and** Indicator tables has 4 column:Share Price; Common Shares Outstanding,date,id(foreign key)
I tried company tables and i successfully insert data into it using following code logic:

```
with open('testss.csv', newline='') as f_input:
csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
block = []
for row in csv_input:
    if len(row):
        if row[0] == 'id':
            if block:
                print(block)
            block = [row]
        else:
            block.append(row)
for i in range(1,len(block[0])):
    print (block[0][0]+" : "+block[0][i])
    print (block[1][0]+" : "+block[1][i])
    print (block[2][0]+" : "+block[2][i])
    print (block[3][0]+" : "+block[3][i])
```

I did not understand how to insert data in indicator table like this:

```
id|date      |SharePrice | Common Shares Outstanding
12|2011-11-04| 2.72      | 65046.232
13|2011-11-04|2.33       | 3443
```

Please give some logic(code Example) to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to read the file in two parts: first the company part(what you have done), next the indicator one, that starts after the *indicator* line. While reading the company part, my advice is to set a mapping where the key is the first column and the value the full row: it will be used next to process the indicator part, because the id will be the element of the *id* row and same index, and the column name will the element of the *indicator* row and still same index.

The code could become:

```
c_part = {}
with open('testss.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in csv_input:                 # first process the company part
        c_part[row[0]] = row
        if row[0] == 'indicator': break   # up to the indicator line
    # ok, we have the companies
    companies = { ( c_part['id'][i], c_part['company'][i],
                    c_part['ticker'][i], c_part['industry code'][i] )
                  for i in range(1, len(c_part['id'])) }
    print(companies)
    for row in csv_input:                 # now the indicator part
        date = row[0]
        data = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            data[c_part['id'][i]][c_part['indicator'][i]] = row[i]
        for i in data:
            data[i].update({'id': i, 'date': date})  # update with the date and id part
            print(dict(data[i]))          # this is a line of the indicator table
```

Comment: It work fine on small file but i have large(325Mb) file.In this case show me error: for i in range(1, len(c_part['id'])) } KeyError: id

Comment: @chandrashekhardas: is the format of the large file the same (meaning one single companies part at top of file with 4 lines followed by the indicators part) and how many fields are present on each line?

Comment: If the indicator are same for individuals id then it's work fine.But my case indicator filed not for the same as their id.e.g.(id 14 has no indicator filed like' Common Shares Outstanding'. in this case it's will show Keyerror.ok it's fine if i set data[i]['Common Shares Outstanding'] =0 in try block .it set to zero and stop the iteration.How to handle this plz some suggestion.

Comment: @chandrashekhardas can you show some input data exhibiting the problem ? It will be easier to fix if I can reproduce

Comment: The problem is that in the big file, the id name is no longer `'id'` but `'SimFin ID'`. But that's not all. The file contains 59 indicators and 19 different companies. So each line should contain 1+ 59 * 19 (1122) fields but it only contains 1024 ones. I assume you have loaded it in a spreadsheet program like Excel that only accepts 1024 columns. And you failed to say whether you only need a subset of the indicators or the whole list...  I do not need all the lines to test a program against the file, but I do need all the columns!